# Adding Multiple Filters to Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to learn about pivot tables and ran into some useful sample data to test my knowledge, especially in A/B testing.

[image]

I have about 20,000 data sets like the above table. I want to use a pivot table to see filter certain parameters, kind of like an A/B test.

Lets say I implemented some changes to an audience, selected by:

1. Odd Number user ID
2. Date of Registration after September 30th, 2017
3. only IOS and NOT Android with App version after 5.

I want to see if people under the above filters bought our feature ("Yes" or "No") and compare it to the people that this specific feature wasn't rolled out to and see if the feature had some impact.

Using Pivot Tables, I'd be nice to measure this, filtering out the people that fit the criteria versus the people that don't, and see if the sum of feature bought has some difference.

Is Pivot Table the right idea to measure this? Can someone provide some help on how I can approach this?

I guess assuming this is a pivot table, the flexibility to see if the user's bitcoin or the specific phone model had impact could be useful too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Pivot Table is a good way to tackle this. The cool thing about PivotTables is that they are easy to copy. So whip one up, put the UserID in the Values area, change the aggregation to Count, and then make multiple copies of the PivotTable. Then go make changes to different filters, and compare the counts.

Plenty of PivotTable tutorial on YouTube. Suggest you add "Mike Girvin" or "ExcelIsFun" to your google search terms, as Mike has hundreds of great videos on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks! I was just having trouble trying to make sense of the results because I needed two pivot tables to compare.

Comment: You can set up formulas to reference comparitive cells in each PivotTable using the GETPIVOTDATA function. That's a real handy function because it doesn't care if fields get moved around in the PivotTable...it happily goes and fetches the value you specify by looking for the intersection of fields. You can make it dynamic too, so that it gets input from a user. Give Google a spin for more info. Pleas mark my answer as accepted if it solves your issue.